# Alternative TikZ drivers for tex4ht. Installation and first steps

Tags: tex4ht

I am new to `tex4ht` but not to `tex` or `pdflatex`.
Since I could not correctly get text inside `TikZ` figures, I tried the solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543919/what-are-the-limitations-of-using-tikz-with-tex4ht/543984#543984).
I've copied the `pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def` file to the *home* tree:

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/dvisvgm4ht/
```

and now the tex to html conversion happens.
So at this point I have two questions:

1. It is possible to put that file somewhere else in the `texlive` *local* tree? (see edit-note below). I found it really strange having system files in the user path.
2. Is that all for `tex4ht` to work well with `TikZ` pictures? In that case, what is the purpose of the `pgfsys-tex4ht-updated.def` file?

**edit:**

If I ask the system, I get:

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
$HOME/texmf
```

This folder doesn't exist. However, placing the driver at

```
$HOME/texmf/tex/latex/pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def
```

makes `tex4ht` work fine. On the other hand,

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/share/texmf
```

But placing the driver at

```
/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def
```

doesn't work UNLESS YOU REFRESH THE INDEX OF THAT TREE:

```
texhash /usr/local/share/texmf
```

So is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ad 1) you can use any [local texmf tree](http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-what-TDS).
ad 2) I've found that the README file was not really clear. It should be a bit better now. `pgfsys-tex4ht-updated.def` can be used if you want a faster compilation, but results with `pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def` almost always looks better.

Comment: I have read the link, but it is still unclear to me. Now your answer refers to the "local" texmf tree while the dvisvgm4ht readme talks about the "home" texmf tree. I have edited the question to add more information.

Comment: Finally, I have it working by refreshing the texmf local tree.

Comment: @e_moro I personally always use the TEXMFHOME tree, because I am the only user of my computer and it seems easier to manage, as you don't need root privileges to access it and you also don't need to run `texhash`. I guess that the advantage of the TEXMFLOCAL tree is that it works for multiple users.